# Where is the default init for UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

So I've recently run into this issue where some Swift 5 code I've written compiles in Xcode 11.0 but not 11.2.1, and the latter complained that there was no default initializer for my class extending UIViewController (it defines no initializers) when I try to instantiate it.

Indeed, when I look at the definition for UIViewController, these are the only two definitions:

```
public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)
public init?(coder: NSCoder)
```

It also contains a comment which seems to imply there should be a default initializer present as well, but I can't find it.

```
/*
  The designated initializer. If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this
  method, even if you aren't using a NIB.  (As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you,
  and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.) In the specified NIB, the File's Owner proxy should
  have its class set to your view controller subclass, with the view outlet connected to the main view. If you
  invoke this method with a nil nib name, then this class' -loadView method will attempt to load a NIB whose
  name is the same as your view controller's class. If no such NIB in fact exists then you must either call
  -setView: before -view is invoked, or override the -loadView method to set up your views programatically.
*/
```

I've found a workaround to make this work, I just have to define all three initializers calling into the superclass initializers, with the default working as described in the comment, but I'm still perplexed how I've gotten away with using the default initializer all this time when I can't find it anywhere. Where is the default initializer described in the comment actually defined?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this thing happens when you define a variable and do not initialize it. So if there is such variable in you code like-

```
var name:string
```

change it like

```
var name:string = ""
```

or

```
var name = string()
```

Comment: I am very confident this is not the cause; my class has no members. Also, isn't it an error if your initializer leaves one of the members uninitialized? I don't think my workaround would fix this if it were the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cant find `init()` decladation because it is a convenience initializer.

When you attempt to override it Xcode will give you this error:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

and this message:

> 1. Attempt to override convenience initializer here (UIKit.UIViewController)

And you cant override the convenience initializers in Swift, and the convenience initializer must call one of the self.init’s not one of the superclass.

```swift
convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to override it, I'm trying to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call init() as default constructor.

```
import UIKit

class InstantWebViewController: UIViewController {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    init(_ object: [String: Any?]?) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The first three initializers is basically exactly what I did to work around the issue. I'm trying to understand where the default initializer for UIViewController actually comes from, though.